# Deep Learning / Keras : Should I use a very small learning rate for very small data (Input and Output values)?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I am trying to train a neural network, supervised, with a big set of data (let say over 1 mio samples).

The NN should solve a regression problem; it takes 4 input numerical values and predicts one numerical value. The values are scaled between 0 and 1.

Each sample in the training set looks like:

```
Input-set->

[
[0.47860402, 0.31794003, 0.00013333333, 0.00026666667],

[0.47860357, 0.31794018, 0.00013333333, 0.00026666667],

…

[0.47859928, 0.317943, 0.00013333333, 0.00026666667]
]

Output-Set ->

[0.657721

0.65772104 

0.6577211  

... 

0.69796   

0.69796 

0.69796   ]
```

As you can see there are really small changes between each datasample, like in the 6th place after point.
I am using the following model

```
model = keras.Sequential([
              
               keras.layers.Dense(50,input_shape=(4,),activation="relu",kernel_initializer ='he_uniform'),
               keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
               keras.layers.Dropout(0.1),
               keras.layers.Dense(25,activation="relu",kernel_initializer ='he_uniform'),
               keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
               keras.layers.Dropout(0.1),
    
               keras.layers.Dense(1,activation="relu"),
            ])

opt = keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.005)
model.compile(loss='mse',optimizer=opt)
```

I am struggling to find a good model, which could solve the given problem. In some predictions I get just a straight line instead of a curve.

My question is, do I use a big learning rate ? Should I use a learning rate like 0.00001 because of the small changes ? Or is there another problem ? I am not experienced in machine learning so I hope an expert here could give me some ideas :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The obvious problem is you are using `relu` in the last dense layer. You need to make your last dense layer a linear layer. With other words, if you are doing regression, you don't need to use non-linearity function like `relu` in the last dense layer.

Also, you really don't need to use regularization techniques unless you are over-fitting but I did not remove them here.

I changed model as:

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
                      
                       tf.keras.layers.Dense(50,input_shape=(4,),activation="relu",kernel_initializer ='he_uniform'),
                       tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
                       tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.1),
                       tf.keras.layers.Dense(25,activation="relu",kernel_initializer ='he_uniform'),
                       tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
                       tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.1),
            
                       tf.keras.layers.Dense(1),
                    ])
        
opt = tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop() # you can also use adam
model.compile(loss='mse',optimizer=opt)
```

Some epochs:

```
Epoch 39/100
32/32 [==============================] - 0s 5ms/step - loss: 0.0812 - val_loss: 0.0888
Epoch 40/100
32/32 [==============================] - 0s 5ms/step - loss: 0.0833 - val_loss: 0.0864
```

Predictions:

```
y_hat = model.predict(X_test)
y_hat[:10]

array([[0.47433853],
       [0.4804499 ],
       [0.4659953 ],
       [0.4893798 ],
       [0.38975602],
       [0.53456545],
       [0.5105466 ],
       [0.45408142],
       [0.4651251 ],
       [0.5104909 ]], dtype=float32)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the hints. I will try it :)

Comment: I used 1000 samples for fitting, loss values may vary according to sample size. Also if your problem is solved, kindly consider accepting the answer in SO.

Comment: "don't use normalization unless you are overfitting" This advice makes no sense, normalization has nothing to do with overfitting